# admob at fullscreen activity

Tags: java, android, admob

My goal is create app without project name title and with admob banner at bottom.
Here is my code

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

AdView adView = (AdView) this.findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
    .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
    .addTestDevice("ca-app-pub-74954863xxxxxxx/1716006131")
    .build();
adView.loadAd(adRequest);
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();

LinearLayout myLayout= ( LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.puzzle_surface);
...........
puzzleSurface = new Puzzle(this);
puzzleSurface.setPuzzle(myPuzzle);
myLayout.addView(puzzleSurface);
```

But as result I get fullscreen without AdMob banner. It persists and can be clicked but not seen. 
It's also the same result with changing App style in Manifest file:

```
        <activity android:name=".MyActivity"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
             >
```

So how can I remove app project name title and display Admob simultaneously?

Comment: are you talking about interstitials admob?

Comment: what do you mean "interstitials"? I just want to create app with main activity, admob banner and without project name title at top.

Comment: ok ok, but this big fullscreened admob ads are called interstitials

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to add `adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);` or `Smart_Banner` in the setAdSize method

Answer (score 0):

try
AdSize adSize = new AdSize(600, 50);

before
adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);